# VBA - Worksheet activate macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dropdownlist on a spreadsheet which has a macro when particular items are selected. E.g. if they choose "Yes", some cells are unhidden.

I am trying to update this value using VBA, e.g. `SheetName.Range("OptionDropDown").value = "Yes"`

when this runs I want also the activation on the worksheet to run, however it just inputs the value but does not run the macro behind it to unhide the sheets. I've tried turning on/off autocalc with no luck. If I go into the spreadsheet and press enter on the cell the macro works

Comment: Hi There, is your macro initializing on sheet change event ?

Comment: Hi Apurv, you are correct it is

Comment: why not call the update event in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If this needs to trigger each time the dropdown item is changed, I would suggest using the worksheet_change function.

in the sheets VBA page (Terminology isn't great, sorry!)

```
sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target as Range)

if instr(1,target.address,"letter of column effected"),1)>0 then

     'run code here
else
'Do nothing or other stuff
End if
```

This will trigger each time a cell changes, which in this instance would be the cell linked to the dropdown box or the cell set to pull a value based on the drop down.

Hope this helps

Comment: You've got one opening bracket on the INSTR line and two closing brackets (not sure what the `,1)` is for).  Might be better to use `IF Target.Column=3` or `IF Target.Address="$C$3" THEN`